# How to Modify an SSRS Matrix Report to Display Averages of Totals?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2016 to build a report object involving a matrix.  I want my rows to sum at the far right, but my columns need to be an average of the values in a given group.  I want to do this in SSRS as opposed to aggregating in TSQL.  My report, thus far, looks like this:
[image: summary report]

The intended result is for the first column of data to average to 2 and the next 2 columns to average to 1.

The SQL that drives the report is as follows:

```
DECLARE @year int = 2021
DECLARE @hpcode varchar(200) = 'BB'

/*Internal variables*/
DECLARE @month int = 1
DECLARE @monthend int = 12
DECLARE @table table (MEMB_KEYID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, MEMBID varchar(50), RLSHIP varchar(2),
RELATIONSHIP varchar(50), HPCODE VARCHAR(10), OPT VARCHAR(25), EMPGROUP VARCHAR(40), 
COMPANY_ID VARCHAR(10), MONTHDATE date)

/*If current year is selected, only grab up to current month*/
IF (YEAR(GETDATE()) = @year)
   BEGIN
          SET @monthend = MONTH(GETDATE())
   END

WHILE @month<=@monthend
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @table (MEMB_KEYID, MEMBID, RLSHIP, RELATIONSHIP, HPCODE, OPT, EMPGROUP, COMPANY_ID, MONTHDATE)
   SELECT MHP.MEMB_KEYID, MMV.MembID, mmv.rlship,
   CASE 
   when mmv.RLSHIP = '18' then  'Subscriber'
   when mmv.RLSHIP in ('01','53') then 'Spouse'
   else 'Child/Other Dependent' end as RELATIONSHIP,
   MHP.HPCODE, MHP.OPT, EMPGROUP, MHP.COMPANY_ID, DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,1)
   FROM MEMB_HPHISTS MHP
   INNER JOIN MEMB_MASTER_V MMV on MMV.MEMB_KEYID = MHP.MEMB_KEYID

   WHERE ISNULL(MHP.OPTHRUDT, DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,1) ) >= DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,1)
          and MHP.OPFROMDT <= EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,1))
   AND MHP.HPCODE in (@hpcode)
   and mmv.MembID NOT LIKE 'TEMP%'
   

   /*Increment @month*/
   SET @month = @month+1
END
 /*Grab data*/
 SELECT Memb_KEYID, MembID, RLSHIP, RELATIONSHIP, HPCode, OPT, EMPGROUP, COMPANY_ID, MonthDate 
 from @Table
```

My report layout is [image: here]
When I try to run the report, an error is thrown:

```
The value expression for the text box txtOPTAverageCount has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.
```

How do I accomplish this type of summary?

Comment: Is it the total line you want to show as 2,1,1 in the example? Also, what expression is in the main cells (e.g. the 2 in the first row)

Comment: The totals would be 2, 1, 1, 4 which are the averages of the counts.  Each cell is an aggregate = Count(MembID)

Comment: I've just modified my answer to base it on an average of counts

Comment: You have the scope name in the outer expression, it should be in the inner expression. `=AVG(COUNT(Fields!MembID.Value, "grpMonthDate"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the report design it's hard to tell but assuming that you have a row group that groups by date, let's also assume that this row group is called `grpDate`.

Finally I will assume the the main data cells have an expression something like `=COUNT(Fields!MembID.Value)`

What you need to do is get the sum of each row group and average the results, like this...

```
=AVG(COUNT(Fields!MembID.Value, "grpDate"))
```

Note that the row group name must be enclosed in quotes and is case sensitive

Comment: If this does not answer your question, please post your report design

Comment: I've just updated my question to include a snippet of the layout and current error message.

Comment: You have put the scope name in the outer expression, this is wrong, it should be in the inner expression. `=AVG(COUNT(Fields!MembID.Value, "grpMonthDate"))` If you look at my answer, that's how it shoudl be done.